# How to save array to an attribute of an entity?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data

I have a question about core data. I have an **Entity** named **`User`** and this entity has 3 attributes: `name, images, videos`. How can  I save an array of multiple images or videos to the attributes images or videos?

Comment: what do you have so far? Show us pls your code.

Answer (score 3):

With relational databases, whenever you have one attribute that is going to have a bunch of values for a single entity, you have a one to many relationship and you actually need another entity. So in a strict relational database, you would create a new entity, Image, that had one column pointing to the image's data and a second column pointing to the user that that image is associated with, a foreign key. In CoreData, they represent these foreign key columns as a relationship. So you'll have to make a new entity for each 1-to-M(any) relationship you have and give them a relationship back to user, and in turn user to them.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/14742/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-how-to-work-with-relations-and-predicates), it may help you.